# Method "split" not found in [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]

Tags: powershell, split

in my script I want to read a csv-file into an array and split the text in the first column.

The file consists a table with 2 columns. In the first column there are the personal names with the short Usernames in brackets. In the second column are the position of the user.

```
User:
Hoch,Susane (HOCH05)
Albrecht, Melanie (ALBRE05)

Department:
Managment
Salesoffice
```

I read the first column in an array and want to split every char after the first "(". So the I have got "Hoch, Susanne" instead of "Hoch, Susane (HOCH05)".

I get the following error message:
    [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] contains no method with the name "Split".

The type of the variable "$value is:

```
    IsPublic IsSerial Name                            BaseType                                                                                                      
    -------- -------- ----                            --------                                                                                                        
    True     False    PSCustomObject                  System.Object
```

I can´t find my misstake.

Here is my code:

```
$Arrayusername_ads_unique = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$AD_User = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$AD_User_table = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$username_AD = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$Arrayusername_ads_unique = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Userabgleich\Liste-original\User_ADS-utf8.csv"

$Arrayusername_ads_unique | Out-File C:\temp\Userabgleich\output-temp\User_ADS-utf8.csv -Append -Encoding utf8

$AD_User = Import-CSV 'C:\temp\Userabgleich\output-temp\User_ADS-utf8.csv' -Delimiter ";" | sort User

$AD_User_table = $AD_User | Select-Object User

foreach ($value in $AD_User_table)
{
    $value.GetType()
    $username_AD = $value.Split("(")
}
```

Comment: This does not look like a CSV file with (named) columns at all. If it really IS a CSV file, please show us a few of the (sanitized) lines of the original. The first three lines will do.

Comment: Try: `"$Value".Split('(')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you did not provide a proper CSV to test against, i made a guess at what it would look like. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- uses the `.Split()` method to split on the `(`
- takes the 1st result of that split
- trims away any leading/trailing whitespace
- sends the result to the `$Names` collection
- displays the content of that collection

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
User,Department
"Hoch,Susane (HOCH05)","Managment"
"Albrecht, Melanie (ALBRE05)","Salesoffice"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Names = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $IS_Item.User.Split('(')[0].Trim()
    }

$Names
```

output ...

```
Hoch,Susane
Albrecht, Melanie
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `foreach` loop to achieve the results:

```
foreach ($value in $AD_User_table)
{
    ($value.user -split "\(")[0]
}
```

I am splitting on the `.user` property of `$value` to retrieve the value you are after in string format. By default, $value is going to be a `[PSCustomObject]` with a property called `User`. I am retrieving index 0 (`[0]`) because your `-split` match will consume a line of output whether or not you choose to keep the output.

If you are only looping to retrieve this particular result, you can accomplish this without a loop using regex substitution and named captures:

```
$ad_user_table.user -replace "(?<Name>.*?)\(.*",'${Name}'
```